# How to get the selected row of a tree table?

Tags: java, xml, jsf, tree

I have a tree table with two columns on a page.
The first one is the parent and the second one is the child.
The child table are displayed as command link, as I click on these links, it should take the Id of the child and display the data on the next page based on the ID.

The problem is, as I select any of the child,it navigates to the next page and only displays the data relating to the first child, which means it takes on the Id of the first child in all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helpse you

```
//TreeViewer viewer use your viewer
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();
```